# Android. Robolectric. How to mock service bounded using aidl?

Tags: android, robolectric

```
private void mockService(IInAppBillingService service){
    IBinder iBinder = Mockito.mock(IBinder.class);
    Mockito.when(iBinder.queryLocalInterface(Mockito.anyString())).
            thenReturn(service);
    Shadows.shadowOf(RuntimeEnvironment.application).setComponentNameAndServiceForBindService(
            new ComponentName("com.android.vending.billing", "IInAppBillingService"), iBinder);
}
```

This is my test code. And I am confused what the component name should be.

This is how I connect to the service in the code:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
        serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
        List<ResolveInfo> intentServices = context.getPackageManager().
                queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0);
        if (intentServices != null && !intentServices.isEmpty()) {
            // service available to handle that Intent
            context.bindService(serviceIntent, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        } else {
            // no service available to handle that Intent
            onNoServiceAvailable(failureMethodName);
        }
```

Comment: Did you find the answer? Otherwise, I will dig in Robolectric code

Comment: @EugenMartynov: Did *you* find the answer?

Comment: No, long time I stopped using robolectric